# Z-index not working on pseudo-element with clip-path

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a border to my clip path using pseudo-elements. I have already tried to change positioning in them and my pseudoelement still stay on top of it. How can I change this?
You can see my code in here.

```css
#shield {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Bras%C3%A3o_Porto_Feliz.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#shield::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  content:"";
  display: block;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  
}
```

```html
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" id="shield">
          </div>
```

To see what I wanted to be in top of things, just delete the ::before element

Full example is in [here](http://codepen.io/mrasousa/pen/MpMyZd)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip it around. Use your background image in your ::after and your black color for the actual div.

```css
#shield {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  position: relative;
  
  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#shield::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  content:"";
  display: block;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Bras%C3%A3o_Porto_Feliz.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; 
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="shield"></div>
```

Comment: Well, I thought it would have another way to do this... but I think I can work with it. Now that I see, I feel stupid for not having this idea before. Appreciated man!
Cheers

Comment: No problem man, theres a million ways to do about anything and im ussually stuck on the one that doesnt work either so weve all been there to.  Im stuck a multi-dimensional array thats created by a PHP api call... =(